# Error opening file outside of current working directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I moved a file into my current directory but am not able to open it outside of said directory:

```
from pathlib import Path
data_folder = Path("C:/Users/xxxx/data/")
file_to_open = data_folder / "test.txt"
f = open(file_to_open)
print(file_to_open.read_text())
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\file_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = open(file_to_open)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\data\\test.txt'
```

Answer (score -1):

Its because of the windows file path specified in the code given has some error's(its probably a windows only issue).Its due the difference in the way the path is specified.

```py
data_folder = Path(r"C:\Users\xxxx\data\") #raw string
# or use Path('C:\\Users\\xxxx\\data\\')
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is completely wrong. `Path("C:/Users/xxxx/data/")` is also a valid path in Windows.

Comment: Yes, in the pathlib documentation, it specifies that you are able to use forward slashes on Windows. That's why I'm wondering if it's simply a file permissions issue

Comment: Thanks for the response,i am sorry about the wrong information,should i edit it?Is it a file permission issue?